# Ubuntu 22.04 uninstall remove build-in screenshot tool

Tags: 22.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I use flameshot, and I don't want the built-in tool.

I disabled shortcuts in gnome settings, but with no effect

I tried to:

```
>>:~$ sudo apt remove gnome-screenshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gnome-screenshot' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It cannot be accessed trough "Ubuntu Software" center.

How to get rid of the built-in screenshot tool?

Answer (score 3):

The built-in screenshot tool is, well… built-in! So you can't easily get rid of it, not without rebuilding GNOME.

But you can get it out of your way! This is done by going to Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, look for "screenshot" there and remove every shortcuts for the built-in screenshot tool.

You can also add a custom shortcut for Flameshot there. Go to Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts section, click on the plus (+) sign, type in a name for your shortcut (like "Run Flameshot"), then a command (like "flameshot gui -c -g") and finally choose your favourite keyboard shortcut for it. I chose Super+PrtScr, but you may just use strait PrtScr, if you actually disassociated it from the built-in screenshot tool before.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22 today, and I was struggling with the native screenshot intercepting every call to other utilities (e.g. Flameshot). Turning off Wayland made it stop.

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m):

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Reboot.