# Screen Share Not working in Ubuntu 22.04 (In all platforms zoom, teams, google meet, anydesk , etc.,)

Tags: screen, 22.04, sharing

Ubuntu 22.04 has a bug which is we can't share our screen on any platforms.

Comment: What does it look like when you can't share your screen? For me, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have the share screen button, and can click through fine to share a screen, and it switches as if it's about to share screen on the view for others. But it then doesn't share my screen, just the Teams view of my user icon. If, however, I leave the meeting and come back once or twice or sometimes 3-5 times, the screen share starts working. I'm using X11 by default, not wayland, because my laptop has an Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The issue with Ubuntu 22.04 is that it now uses a display feature called *wayland* by default, while in versions prior to 21.04 Ubuntu defaulted to using xorg as its display server. Wayland does not support screen sharing by default (until now, at least!).

To check which display system your Ubuntu is using, please enter this command

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If the above command outputs **wayland**, your system is using wayland.

In order to use screen sharing, we have to disable wayland and enable xorg (x11). To do this,

Please go to this file

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment this line.

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Reboot your system.

Voila! You can share your screen. You can confirm this by re-entering this command.

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

Now it should display **x11**.

If **x11** is not shown yet, run the command below:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you. I've had this issue ever since upgrading to 22.04, I'm still shocked this question barely has any upvotes.

Comment: after I did that, the screen sharing is working but it's super slow

Comment: people using DisplayLink could have problems because of x11 compatibility (using 2 displays through a docking station, for example)

Comment: The minimum qualification for using Ubuntu should be to be a stackexchange user lol. This is really bad practice they break functionality in a stable upgrade.

Comment: this solution diables all swipe gestures

Comment: No it's not. Everything will work just like Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: this gets you working with thirty year old tech, a more modern solution: see [next answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421314/139044) (enabling chrome pipewire support)

Comment: I think the author of this answer should **warn** people that other issues can be compromised by downgrading to Xorg, such as [this case](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414283/980324), for example.

Comment: How could Wayland be shipped in a LTS with such a big problem?

Comment: This also worked for me. On X11 now and everything is working as supposed to. I guess it will take another 15 years for them to sort this Wayland bs out ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So, there is no disadvantage of using X11 instead of Wayland?

Comment: Then my second monitor turn into black screen after reboot...

Comment: problem with x11 I have: touch screen not working properly, any dialog window has no focus -> which is super anoying. This shouldn't be accepted answer.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  As others have said, while downgrading _might indeed help the problem_, I just don't feel like downgrading is the _right_ solution.

Comment: @gordon_freeman Once you select your user in the login screen, a cog-like button appears in the lower right corner. Clicking on it let's you select "Ubuntu on Xorg" vs "Ubuntu" (which defaults to Wayland). It will remember this preferences for your user.

Comment: @DBencz indeed, I was using gnome gesture improvements https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4033/x11-gestures/, however when switching to X11 it no longer works. I had to use https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4245/gesture-improvements/ gesture improvements for X11 instead and was able to get gestures back (three finger swipe to reveal all windows and horizontal three finger swipe to change desktop), it is less customizable indeed, but at least we get functionality back.

Comment: If I do this, my computer doesn't boot, is someone experimenting this issue? I had to set back the `WaylandEnable=false`

Comment: Simply logging in with xorg seems to be more appropriate for just switching over when screen sharing is desired

Comment: @matanster how do you do this? I don’t see any such option on the logging screen.

Answer (score 59):

**Only works for web browser**

Go to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` using the address bar of your browser.

[image]

Click the drop down menu, and click Enabled.

[image]

Finally Restart the browser

This will enable the browser to prompt screenshare access

Comment: This worked like a charm for me.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me and without the need of switching to Xorg.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't need to reboot the system, just restart the chrome.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur thanks for the suggestion will update

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Chrome, Teams and Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland and who know what other components are relevant to this

Comment: This worked for me in the Brave browser as well.

Comment: This solution is bettern then activating X11 because X11 can cause other problems such as mouse freez on newer laptops with amd ryzen.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to disable Wayland in favour of X11 as the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I can share only chrome's windows

Comment: The chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer option is no longer there in latest Chrome ...

Answer (score 12):

For **Slack** in-app screen recording and screen sharing **before version 4.33.90** (the entire video capture got broken in or around 4.33.90, so I'm unable to test screen recording):

1. Quit the Slack app completely (use `Quit` from the tray icon).
2. In the terminal:

```sh
slack --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer
```

3. See if it works.
4. (Optional) Persist the change across reboots:

```sh
gedit admin:///usr/share/applications/slack.desktop
```

In text editor find a line that says:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/slack %U
```

Change the line to say:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/slack --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer %U
```

That's it. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04LTS and:

```sh
$ slack --version
4.27.156

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

$ dpkg -l | grep -i pipewire
ii  libpipewire-0.3-0:amd64                    0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server
ii  libpipewire-0.3-common                     0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         all          libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - common files
ii  libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64              0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - modules
ii  libspa-0.2-modules:amd64                   0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         amd64        libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server Simple Plugin API - modules
ii  pipewire:amd64                             0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         amd64        audio and video processing engine multimedia server
ii  pipewire-bin                               0.3.48-1ubuntu1                         amd64        PipeWire multimedia server - programs
ii  pipewire-media-session                     0.4.1-2ubuntu1                          amd64        example session manager for PipeWire
```

Source: https://github.com/flathub/com.slack.Slack/issues/101#issuecomment-808430530

Comment: Slack (Snap 4.33.90 64-bit)  appears to completely ignore this option.  When I dump the logs for troubleshooting it does not show it as something that got configured.   By setting the pipewire flag in chrome (above), I can share screens when I run Slack in a Chrome tab.  It is just the electron app that doesn't work.  Also, FWIW, the snap version of slack complains vociferously if you try to edit the desktop file (which is in the /opt/snap folder) even as root.

Comment: @rotten Yeah, thanks. Previously video capture didn't work, whereas now on 4.33.90  (electron non-snap) the whole process segfaults with a sole syslog line `[0908/160234.011451:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found` which comes from [crashpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/crashpad/crashpad/snapshot/elf/elf_dynamic_array_reader.h?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F) (so it's probably a bug in crash handling, unrelated to the root cause).

Answer (score 8):

Since Wayland is not supporting screen share by default, there is already an experimental way with chrome browser.

First you need to export the metadata API from the pipewire media sessions.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/
sudo sed -i 's/#metadata/metadata/g' /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/media-session.conf
```

At chrome experimental features enable the WebRTC PipeWire support

```
chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer
```

Restart the browser and now you can share your screen.

Comment: Is this still a valid patch these days?

Comment: @matanster No, this experimental flag doesn’t exist anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the `global.context.unsafe_mode=true` solution, but Google Meet was still showing black screens, so didn't test it any further.

What worked for me was switching to X11/Xorg, which I did by

- logging off
- clicking gear icon at bottom right
- selecting "Ubuntu on Xorg"
- logging back in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned this is a Security Feature of Wayland. You can either use XOrg or disable the save mode of Wayland by doing:

1. Press `Alt` + `F2`
2. Type `lg` and press enter
3. Disable save mode by typing `global.context.unsafe_mode=true` and enter

This will work till you reboot/log out. I wrote a small Gnome Extension which does can disable the safe mode on demand. See https://github.com/julianpollmann/zoom-wayland-gnome-extension

Comment: that did not work for me

Comment: `alt-f2` brings up the headphones volume control for me.   `lg` as a command doesn't exist.

Comment: @polyte, this works for me. Useful since sharing appears broken again in 5.15.12.7665. NOTE: It appears your plugin simply logical NOTs the current value for `global.context.unsafe_mode` rather than setting it to `true` when the switch is on and `false` when it's off. This means if you previously manually set it to `true` before installing your plugin your state will be backwards (as I did). I suggest having the switch determine if you set it to `true` or `false` in the plugin to avoid this. I created a PR to change this (warning, untested :)).

Comment: @rotten you might need to press a function (fn) key. Depends on your (laptop) keyboard. See https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Developer_tools

Comment: That does not work as a shortcut to open a text window on my laptop.  alt/control/function or any combination of them.   It is ok, I always have a dozen or more windows open already.  The "lg" command does not exist on my machine either.  It must be a separate package that needs to be installed.

Comment: @rotten lg is not a installable package. Alt+F2 will bring up the gnome prompt dialogue and lg will open the gnome debugger. This does not work in your normal shell.

Comment: There seems to also be a gnome extension for it. https://github.com/linushdot/unsafe-mode-menu?tab=readme-ov-file. although the above makes it simpler through just one shell command.

Answer (score 3):

I changed graphic drivers (in additional drivers menu) from xorg-server to Nvidia proprietary. It worked for me.

Comment: Replacing the Nvidia Nouveau driver with the proprietary one did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I have a computer with a Nvidia EVGA Geforce GTX - 1660 Super graphic card with a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS OS and none of the above answers worked for my case. Neither the chrome flag, neither dismissing the safe mode of wayland and neither changing to use xorg on logon screen.

What did the job was going into Additional Drivers then select the option `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary, tested)` amongst many others (this one did the job at first so I didn't change anymore).
Previously the selected one was the `Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Same here.  I had to run apt upgrades, then try and switch to this driver a couple of times before it would 'take' without an error.  Then a restart was necessary before screen-sharing actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

Now the screen sharing in Wayland is available with the zoom client for Ubuntu.

[https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205759689#:~:text=Resolved%20an%20issue%20regarding%20sharing%20content%20on%20Gnome%2041%20with%20Wayland%C2%A0](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205759689#:%7E:text=Resolved%20an%20issue%20regarding%20sharing%20content%20on%20Gnome%2041%20with%20Wayland%C2%A0)

Check the release notes in `5.11.0 (3540)` release.

Comment: Still not working. I'm on 5.12 and it is still broken. Changing to x11 was the only thing that worked.

Comment: I'm on 5.16 and it's still broken.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for days I found the solution from this thread only

> I changed graphic drivers (in additional drivers menu) from xorg-server to Nvidia proprietary. It worked for me.

But there are many! So the following one worked for me (just so you guys save time and know this actually works).

And doing the wayland method used to break my display and turn it into -ve colours.

> Using NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535-server (proprietary)

Answer (score 0):

(On Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

Deactivating wayland as the first answer suggests worked the best **but** you have to give up the much better touchpad usess.

Alternatively I found [a solution here](https://devicetests.com/wayland-screen-sharing-status-solutions) that works on the browser version, at least for Zoom and Google Meet.
It requires installing the packages `xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` and `gnome-remote-desktop` and then rebooting:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome gnome-remote-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

While reverting back to x11 did work for me, I wanted to find an alternative that allowed me to continue using Wayland. What ended up working was uninstalling the snap version of zoom and installing the .deb downloaded from Zoom's website

Answer (score -1):

I was resolved by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` and changing the value from `Default` to `Enabled`.

then

Search for the **file.conf** in **/etc/gdm3/** in my case, Ubuntu 20, it's **custom.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

then `reboot`

"*uncommenting that line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland* "

Comment: Please do not copy and paste identical answers to different questions on AU. The system has detected this *exact* answer given to 3 slightly different questions.

Comment: Please do not copy and paste identical answers to different questions on AU. The system has detected this *exact* answer given to 3 slightly different questions.

Comment: This answer mixes two conflicting answers. Do not use it.