# Xorg. When screen sharing, Chome doen't see all programs in progress

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, file-sharing, okular

When I start screen sharing with Google **Chrome** browser, it shows programs in progress except **Okular**, but I need it. Other programs that I tried are shown normally.
Zoom shares the window with Okular. So I am wondering where is the problem, with Chrome or Okular.

Recenty I had problems with screen sharing in Chrome (black screen), so I switched from Wayland to Xorg. Screen sharing works well except with Okular.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64 bits. Version of Gnome 42.1.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, please do so inc. what desktop are you using.

Comment: Ok, thank you !
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64 bits.
Version of Gnome 42.1.