# Screen recording using default Ubuntu screen recorder freezing irregularly

Tags: 22.04, desktop-recording, print-screen

I updated to the new Ubuntu 22.04 recently, and want to screen record using the default feature I get by pressing prtscn. The screenshot feature works well but when I try to take a screen cast or screen recording, it keeps freezing.
For example, it would play just fine up to 0:15 sec and then the screen would just be freezed till maybe 0:30 sec and then it will start playing just fine again.

There's no visible problem when the recording is going on. It's only the end result that has problems.

I was having trouble screen sharing as well, so I changed the display system from wayland to x11 following the answer on [Screen Share Not working in Ubuntu 22.04 (In all platforms zoom, teams, google meet, anydesk , etc.,)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m). I thought that would solve the problem but no luck.

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I have this same issue. One work around is recordmydesktop. It seems to work well for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen

Comment: That seems a bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5585