# ubuntu 22.04, output sound not working when connected to hdmi or docking station, when disconnect sound works fine

Tags: sound, 22.04, output

I am working with a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Gen2.
Up until recently everything worked fine with Ubuntu 22.04.
I did make some adjustments to make share screen possible with zoom ([Screen Share Not working in Ubuntu 22.04 (In all platforms zoom, teams, google meet, anydesk , etc.,)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m)) .

A few days ago output sound stopped working while I am connected to the docking station. I made sure I am using the laptop output as I always do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPOxe.png)

Output does not work, at first the alert did sound, which was strange but after I tried some suggested solution from the web, alerts also stopped working. To my surprise on zoom output sound works.

p.s. Microphone sound works all the time not only for zoom and when connected to docking station or HDMI.

Any idea how to fix this annoying bug ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue
Try to install pavucontrol
It fixed it for me

```
sudo apt-get -y install pavucontrol
```