Cannot install Zoom on 22.04
I'd like to install Zoom on 22.04. This shouldn't be difficult...
Followed these instructions:
Using the terminal 
Download the DEB installer file from our Download Center
Open the download location using a file manager.
Right click in the file manager and click Terminal or Open in Terminal to open the terminal in the current location.
Type in the following command and press Enter to run it.
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb

"Zoom Workplace" appears in my apps.
I open it but get an error. Details:

How do I install Zoom on Ubuntu 22.04?

Are you experiencing difficulty installing it or running it?

@OrganicMarble Hi, in the example above I installed it, then when I run from the GUI, I get the red Ubuntu system error with those details.

Consider editing your post to reflect the actual problem you are experiencing - running the app, not installing it.

@OrganicMarble but how do I know it's installed successfully if I cannot run it?

@OrganicMarble I've just noticed at the end of my install it says N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file '/home/user/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

That N tells you this is a Note and nothing to be concerned about.

@OrganicMarble thanks. To be honest it's probably pointless me getting Zoom installed because apparently 22.04 cannot share screen. Zoom web client, Google Meet.... none of them can. Some nonsense with Wayland. The Linux community really should sort all this sort of nonsense out.

@OrganicMarble Zoom web browser will work but apparently 22.04 has a bug which prevents sharing screen. I was using the web browser yesterday but couldn't share screen. Done some research today and found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m

@OrganicMarble So her age is completely irrelevant because you're managing it all. I'm not a Windows fanboy but she wouldn't even need an admin for Windows. I'm a programmer, hence I use Linux but the Linux community should be embarrassed how difficult it is to install/use apps on Linux.

You're right, I'll delete that stuff. But consider not using wayland and it might work for you.

Try downloading the .deb version of Zoom from their website https://zoom.us/support/download and then using right click, choose the Software Installer.
If you use X11 (Xorg) instead of Wayland then screen sharing works, remote control works, annotations work, etc.

It is hard to say for certain given that I cannot tell how your system is set up. This is how zoom version 6.
Make sure that you are launching zoom correctly. This is usually linked to /usr/bin/zoom or use /opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher directly.
I can give how I install zoom successfully on ubuntu 22.04 running Xorg. I download the deb and then use the terminal to do the install.
I usually download the zoom deb from their download center using a web browser which saves them to the ~/Downloads directory.
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb

sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
/usr/bin/zoom # to launch zoom
# if there are any problems with that, if have a gpu like nvidia which is not
# configured can try
/opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher  --disable-gpu-sandbox 


The --fix-broken install is asking apt to fix them for you:
apt-cache depends reports this on my version of ubuntu 22.04:
apt-cache depends zoom
zoom
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libxcb-keysyms1
  Depends: libxcb-xinerama0
  Depends: libdbus-1-3
  Depends: libxcb-shape0
  Depends: libxcb-shm0
  Depends: libxcb-xfixes0
  Depends: libxcb-randr0
  Depends: libxcb-image0
  Depends: libfontconfig1
  Depends: libxi6
  Depends: libsm6
  Depends: libxrender1
  Depends: libpulse0
  Depends: libxcomposite1
  Depends: libxslt1.1
  Depends: libsqlite3-0
  Depends: libxcb-xtest0
  Depends: libxtst6
  Depends: ibus
    ibus:i386
  Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0
  Depends: desktop-file-utils
    desktop-file-utils:i386
  Depends: libgbm1
  Depends: libdrm2
  Depends: libxcb-cursor0
  Depends: libxcb-icccm4
  Depends: libfreetype6
  Depends: libgbm1
  Recommends: libegl1-mesa
  Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx


Checking that I am running X not Wayland.
echo $DISPLAY
:0


Hi, unfortunately that didn't do anything. I do notice at the end of my install it says: N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file '/home/user/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

can you explain more about your system? I have installed zoom-client many times on 22.04 without difficulty on and/x64 computers. Where did you get the deb from? are you running Xorg or wayland as your graphics server. etc.
