Im having issues with screen sharing in Discord on Ubuntu
I'm quite new to Ubuntu. A month or two ago, I installed Discord from Snap and everything worked properly but after some weeks my Discord couldn't share a screen properly. When I first used Discord it didn't ask me for anything to share screen it just showed me the apps that I could stream and my screen in the "Screens" section. Now there's like a window popping up (sometimes even popping up twice) from the Ubuntu itself that asks for me to choose what I will share then Discord recognizes that whole stream as an app and no other options.


When I choose this option my stream doesn't start and it just loads infinitely. I ran Discord from the terminal to see the logs and saw this when trying to share the screen:
mainScreen.UpdaterEvents: UPDATER_HISTORY_QUERY_AND_TRUNCATE
mainScreen.UpdaterEvents: UPDATER_HISTORY_QUERY_AND_TRUNCATE
Warning: terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 2.  Skipping ICD.

[8202:0605/220724.883923:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
'loop->recurse > 0' failed at ../src/pipewire/thread-loop.c:426 pw_thread_loop_wait()
'loop->recurse > 0' failed at ../src/pipewire/thread-loop.c:426 pw_thread_loop_wait()
'loop->recurse > 0' failed at ../src/pipewire/thread-loop.c:426 pw_thread_loop_wait()
'loop->recurse > 0' failed at ../src/pipewire/thread-loop.c:426 pw_thread_loop_wait()
[8145:0605/221335.407648:ERROR:screencast_portal.cc(367)] Failed to start the screen cast session.
[8145:0605/221335.407664:ERROR:base_capturer_pipewire.cc(81)] ScreenCastPortal failed: 2
Error occurred in handler for 'DISCORD_DESKTOP_CAPTURER_GET_SOURCES': Failed to get sources. (The last two lines of error showed up more than once)

Any help would be appreciated.
(My discord at the moment is the 0.0.55.deb)

This has been happening to me for a while now, and is also happening to another person on our team. Ubuntu and discord app are not playing nice to share the screen. I have to share my screen using the web launced discord only.

This question is similar to: Screen Share Not working in Ubuntu 22.04 (In all platforms zoom, teams, google meet, anydesk , etc.,). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This fixed it for me and others.
Steps (detailed explanation of the steps are above):

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
(if it say wayland and not X11 follow with the below)
open the config sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
Change #WaylandEnable=false to WaylandEnable=false
CTRL+O and enter to write out changes & CTRL+X and enter to close the session
Reboot

Your screen sharing should work now.

Another article following the same solution is posted here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1407496/1566786

discord is built using electron, and although electron now has support for screen sharing under wayland, the discord client does not as it still uses an older version of electron.
So your solutions are:

Use the discord web version with a support browser (e.g chrome), a short hand way is the following command


chromium --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --enable-features=WebRTCPipeWireCapturer --app=https://discord.com/app



Use discord canary which can be downloaded here (this is an alpha version of discord and will be unstable

Use a third-party discord client like WebCord or Vesktop (using a third party discord client is against the discord TOS and could get you banned)



Same problem with discord-canary-0.0.501.deb. Does not solve this issue.

I had the same issue with my Ubuntu, I solved it by switching to xorg display mode.
Method:

Sign out of your computer.

Go to log in where it prompts for your
password.

Bottom right hand corner there should be a setting icon.

Click it and switch to xorg display mode.


Sign back in and you should be able to stream again.
Hope this helps!

switching to xorg is not a solution, and please stop suggesting it
