# How to disable/remove default Ubuntu 22.04 screenshot tool

Tags: gnome-screenshot

I want to get rid of this tool because I have an alternative for making screenshots and default tool intercepts Ctrl+Shift+A which I use in my IDE.

Similar question but the answers don't fit my needs
[Ubuntu 22.04 uninstall remove build-in screenshot tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406524/ubuntu-22-04-uninstall-remove-build-in-screenshot-tool)

I already removed all default keybindings for screenshot in Settings->Keyboard but there's no **Ctrl+Shift+A**
I don't think wayland configuration can somehow help me when I'm using X11

**UPD**
I guess you mess up two different tools.
Default screenshot tool (On Print key) looks like this
[image]
[image]

while the `Ctrl+Shift+A` looks like this
[image]

**UPD #2**
As gnome team [stated](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6241#note_1620726), the last screen is not a part of gnome desktop environment. Created a duplicate issue [on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/704152)

**UPD #3**
Oh, it was Lark messenger. Problem solved by disabling this hotkey in its settings

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 and newer, the new Gnome screenshot tool is baked into gnome-shell.

It's not a separate package anymore. It cannot be removed separately from gnome-shell, and there is no setting to disable it.

If you don't want it, then simply ignore the built-in feature and use your preferred application instead.

If the Gnome desktop environment conflicts with your preferred screenshot application, keybindings, and workflow, then:

1. Please file a bug report with Gnome, and/or
2. Try a different desktop environment that does not conflict.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Updated the answer